# html2canvas doesn't work on server

Tags: javascript, php, html2canvas

So I used this script to take screenshot of the div and everything worked fine until I placed in on debian linux server. http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/

It takes empty screenshot of a div.

Things a tried:

- Localhost: works fine
- hostinger.com: works fine
- Debian, PHP Version 5.3.3-7+squeeze14: doesn't work

Tried chmoding. So the only reason I could think of is PHP version. but there's no fancy function all works on this version. So what else?

Comment: The problem here is that _It's not working_ really isn't much info to help you out...

Comment: Well I just made an assumption that someone might have encountered it. Could you tell me what info you need? P.S. When I say that it doesnt work I mean it just saves empty pictures. It does pass dimensions 470x246 which is very strange since if its manage to pass dimensions and save it, it means php should work fine. But JS and html is client-side and I'm using same browser so it doesnt make sense that JS doesnt work on server.. duh.. its anoying. :(

Comment: I encountered this error too. Any solution you found?